# Transposing columns to rows

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I would like to convert my wide data to long data/ transpose the columns (c_lead and mkt_bwon) to rows

Specifically, I would like to convert the columns c_lead and mkt_bwon to rows, where actuals,targets and difference each have rows for c_lead and mkt_bwon etc.

So individual rows labelled mkt_bwon for each of the 'row_names'.

```
select
        'actuals' as row_name,
        cast(period_to as datetime) as  time_period,
        --determinant,
        --sale_location,
        --region,
        coalesce(leads,0) as leads,
        coalesce(opportunities,0) as opps,
        coalesce(b_won,0) as bwon,
        coalesce(cast(total_spend as decimal(18,2)),0) as t_spend,
        coalesce(discount_total,0) as disc,
        (t_spend+disc)  as t_cost,
        (t_spend/leads) as c_lead,
        (t_spend/bwon) as mkt_bwon
    from
         periscope_views.salesforce_deepdive
    where
        determinant = 'online'
union all
         select 'targets'           as row_name,
                date as time_period,
                coalesce(leads, 0)    as leads,
                coalesce(opps, 0)     as opps,
                coalesce(won, 0)      as bwon,
                coalesce(spend, 0)    as t_spend,
                coalesce(discount, 0) as t_disc,
                (t_spend+t_disc) as t_cost,
                (t_spend/leads) as c_lead,
                (t_spend/bwon) as mkt_bwon
         from periscope_views.targets_csv2019
         where source = 'online'
union all
select
       'difference',
       time_period,
       sum(leads) as leads,
       sum(opps) as opps,
       sum(bwon) as bwon,
       sum(t_spend) as t_spend,
       sum(disc) as disc,
       sum(total_cost) as t_cost,
       sum(c_lead) as c_lead,
       sum(mkt_bwon) as mkt_bwon
from
       (
        select
            'actuals' as row_name,
            cast(period_to as datetime) as  time_period,
            --determinant,
            --sale_location,
            --region,
            coalesce(leads,0) as leads,
            coalesce(opportunities,0) as opps,
            coalesce(b_won,0) as bwon,
            coalesce(cast(total_spend as decimal(18,2)),0) as t_spend,
            coalesce(discount_total,0) as disc,
            (total_spend+discount_total) as total_cost,
            (t_spend/leads) as c_lead,
            (t_spend/bwon) as mkt_bwon
        from
             periscope_views.salesforce_deepdive
        where
            determinant = 'online'
    union all
             select 'targets'           as row_name,
                    date as time_period,
                    coalesce(leads, 0)*-1   as leads,
                    coalesce(opps, 0)*-1     as opps,
                    coalesce(won, 0)*-1     as bwon,
                    coalesce(spend, 0)*-1    as t_spend,
                    coalesce(discount, 0)*-1 as t_disc,
                    (t_spend+t_disc)*-1 as t_cost,
                    (t_spend/leads)*-1 as c_lead,
                    (t_spend/bwon)*-1 as mkt_bwon
             from periscope_views.targets_csv2019
             where source = 'online'
     )
    group by time_period,row_name
order by time_period desc
```

The differences part is supposed to simply calculate the difference between actuals and targets

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JonScott I would like to convert the columns (c_lead and mkt_bwon) to rows

Comment: @JonScott so transposing the rows c_lead and mkt_bwon to rows

Comment: for this you use union, which seems to be what you have. please explain the issue?

Comment: @JonScott I am specifically trying to transpose the columns c_lead and mkt_bwon to rows

Comment: Please show how you are trying to do this, and what error you are experiencing. Try using union .